# Can we pass the captured packets as argument to Socket send() function

Tags: python-2.7, networking, tcp, fuzzing

I'm beginner to Networking. We have sender and receiver application. I have captured the packets sent by sender to receiver using WinDump.

I'm writing a python sender application which will fuzz the packets sent by sender to receiver.

I just want to confirm, can I directly put the packet data obtained using WinDump to socket send() method.

Say, "arp who-has host1 tell host2" is the packet obtained by WinDump

Can I write,

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(arp who-has host1 tell host2)
```

Comment: You can send anything you like. Whether a TCP peer will interpret the packet as what it originally was is another question. Sending what appear to be ARP packets over a TCP connection doesn't make any sense to me, but it's your application, only you know what it can do.

Answer (score -1):

In general pyhton network programming you can not pass as the arguments using send method.you just only pass the string as arguments as variable.

Basically we are using the send() and sendall() method to transmits the TCP messages.

I have mentioned the below desciption for both the method.

**socket send() method :**

The socket's `send()` method is not guaranteed to send all of the data you pass it. Instead, it returns the number of bytes that were actually sent and expects your application to handle retransmission of the unsent portion

```
from socket import socket

sock = socket()
sock.connect(('1.2.3.4', 1234))
sock.send('My Name is Dasadiya Chaitanya !!!\n'')
sock.close()
```

**socket sendall() method :**

which is same work as the `send()` method but python provides a convenience method called `sendall()` that makes sure all of your data is sent before returning and also provide the guarantee to send all the data to the receiver.

```
from socket import socket

sock = socket()
sock.connect(('1.2.3.4', 1234))
sock.sendall('My Name is Dasadiya Chaitanya !!!\n')
sock.close()
```

I hope this should helpful for you :)

Comment: That may be what the Python documentation says, although as you haven't provided a citation it is impossible to be sure, but it isn't how the underlying `send()` function actually behaves: therefore it cannot be how Python behaves either. In blocking mode, it blocks until everything you provide has been transferred into the kernel.

Comment: @EJP I am just mentioned that how to pass the message into send () method and  can not pass the multiple arguments in send () method I do not understand why to make my answer as down vote. If i am going me wrong then just ask some things to me.